# Architecture suggestions - How to implement autoscaled async tasks

Tags: python, django, architecture, autoscaling

We have a large application, which uses django as an ORM, and celery as a task running infrastructure.
We run complex pipelines triggered by events (user driven or automatic), which look something like this:

```
def pipeline_a:
# all lines are synchronous, so second line must happen after first is finished successfully
first_res = a1()
all_results = in_parallel.do(a2, a3, a4)
a5(first_res, all_results)
```

We wish to run a1, a2, ... on different machines (each task may need different resources), and the number of parallel running pipelines is always changing.
Today we use celery which is super convenient for implementing the above - but isn't suitable for auto-scaling (we hacked it to work with kubernetes, but it doesn't have native support with it).

Mainly the issues I want to solve are:

1. How to "run the next pipeline step" only after all previous ones are done (I may not know in advance which steps will be run - it depends on the results of previous steps, so the steps are dynamic in nature)
2. Today we try and use kubernetes (EKS) to autoscale some of the tasks (SQS queue size is the hpa metric). How to make kubernetes not try and terminate currently running tasks, but still "start pods" if a new task arrives at the queue (many tasks take ~half an hour to complete)

My experience so far says that to solve 1, celery is the most convenient way, but then it clashes with 2. So How would you solve 1 without celery, and then how could I harness kubernetes for long running tasks?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,

- you have async job which can run upto 30 mins.
- Job are running on K8s.
- Output of current job may decide the next Job.
- You have ability to use SQS.

You can maintain queue for each of task. for each queue implement an consumer. Using Django first add the task to 'a1'. Update the job status in db.

When consumer of a1 finished execution it update the status in db and push to right queue. Let's say 'a3'.
Consumer of 'a3' will read the task. Update the db. Execute. Push the task in right queue. Update the db.

If you use SQS, then you store infinite task in queue. You will have to increase the number of consumer based on size of SQS queue. For this you can use https://github.com/Wattpad/kube-sqs-autoscaler